# SHGetFolderPath doesn't work for me

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have this function:

```
function GetProfilePath: string;
const
  SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;
var
  hToken: THandle;
  ProfilePath: packed array[ 0..MAX_PATH ] of Char;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@ProfilePath[0], SizeOf(ProfilePath));
  OpenProcessToken( GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, hToken );
  SHGetFolderPath( 0, CSIDL_APPDATA, hToken , SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, @ProfilePath[ 0 ] );
  CloseHandle( hToken );
  Result := ProfilePath;
end;
```

SHGetFolderPath returns E_FAIL (0x80004005) and an empty ProfilePath buffer. MSDN says that E_FAIL means "The CSIDL in nFolder is valid, but the folder does not exist". But the folder does exist, I'm pretty sure. When I'm creating a simple test application and running the same code, it works well.

What might be wrong with that?

**update**:
I found that my application doesn't work well when running under Delphi. When I run it separately, all is OK.

Thanks,
Roman

Comment: You **must** check return values from all API calls.

Answer (score 3):

The use of a user token looks needlessly complex. But, having said that, when I ran your code on my machine it worked fine with no error. Perhaps the user token for your process doesn't have sufficient rights to that folder. Or perhaps the folder really does not exist!

For what it's worth I think you would be better off using the simpler off API [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). My wrapper for that looks like this:

```
function GetSpecialFolderPath(const CSIDL: Integer): string;
var
  Buffer: TWin32PathBuffer;
begin
  if SHGetSpecialFolderPath(Application.Handle, @Buffer[0], CSIDL, False) then begin
    Result := Buffer;
  end else begin
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
end;
```

Of course, this may fail in just the same way as your version if the folder really does not exist.

---

OK, I've just re-read this comment in your question:

> When I'm creating a simple test application and running the same code, it works well.

That sounds like you are running the real code in a different context. Perhaps in a service? Or with user impersonation. Maybe that's the clue to solving this. What are you not telling us about the environment/context/setting where the code fails?

---

And some very minor comments on your code. You've defined `ProfilePath` with one more element than needed, and `packed` is superfluous for an array:

```
ProfilePath: array[ 0..MAX_PATH-1 ] of Char;
```

Or, even better, re-use the type defined in the Delphi RTL, `TWin32PathBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Your code seems to be correct, but it raises EOSError exception ("A call to an OS function failed") in my application. "C:\Document and Settings\{user name}\Application Data" folder does exist and used by many other applications.

Comment: See the middle section of my latest update. I'm sure there's something extra about your particular app that you are not telling us yet. Presumably your code (and mine) work just fine in a plain vanilla test app.

Comment: My application is not a service and it doesn't use any impersonation. Actually, I do understand, that context is important, but have no idea which of context details does make sense.

Comment: I found that my application doesn't work well when running under Delphi. When I run it separately, all is OK.

Comment: Are you running Delphi as administrator?

Comment: Yes, sure. And when I run simple test applications under Delphi it works fine.

Comment: Why are you running Delphi as administrator? There should never be a need for that and it's bad practice because you debug in a quite different context.

Comment: @David: if you want automatic updates, you need(ed) to run Delphi elevated or you would get an error message every time you launch it because the setup checker couldn't be run...

Comment: @marjan That was just a design flaw because the emba devs did't properly dogfood. Running as admin evil. Seems to be cured in xe2 at least, prob in xe. More likely this is d6 or d7.

Comment: @David: yeah they did correct it, just not sure in which version... Running D5 under UAC doesn't pose a problem, but d6 already had automatic checking of "Delphi Direct". If that was a separate exe and had something like setup or update in its name, UAC would probably complain.

Comment: Because it's on Windows XP. There isn't any UAC :)